# cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.Rest.Azure.AzureOperationResponse<long> to long

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am developing an Azure Search crawler solution using .NET and Azure Search

When I want to query the count of documents in Azure Search, I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: I haven't used that before but the message makes it sound like CountWithHttpMessagesAsync() has a wrapper around the value you want.  Look for properties/methods on that return object that are like 'Response' or similar to get the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

It returns exactly what it shows in the message box. Changing it to the following will solve the issue but you will still need to 'unwrap' the result.

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchServiceName = "string_service_name";
            string indexName = "indexName";
            string apiKey = "apikey";
            SearchCredentials searchCredentials = new SearchCredentials(apiKey);
            var myIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(searchServiceName, indexName, searchCredentials);
            var result = await myIndexClient.Documents.CountWithHttpMessagesAsync();
            //Microsoft.Rest.Azure.AzureOperationResponse<long> result2 = await myIndexClient.Documents.CountWithHttpMessagesAsync(); This is the same but explicit type
            var longValue = result.Body;
            while (true) ;
        }
```

It returns [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.azure.azureoperationresponse?view=azure-dotnet).
I believe we can unwrap the value by 'getting' the Body (result.Body).

Kind regards